# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'pry-rails'

Tags: ruby, heroku, bundler, pry-rails

I am not familiar with Ruby, but I am anyway trying to install and test iQvoc ( https://github.com/innoq/iqvoc ).
After some initial problems I managed to install it with heroku.
I am trying now to export a small test thesaurus but I have some problems with Ruby.
I use this command:

```
rake --trace iqvoc:export TYPE=ttl NAMESPACE='http://namespace.example.fr/'
```

and I get as result:

```
rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'pry-rails'.
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant Pry::Prompt
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pry-rails-0.3.5/lib/pry-rails/prompt.rb:36:in `<module:PryRails>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pry-rails-0.3.5/lib/pry-rails/prompt.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pry-rails-0.3.5/lib/pry-rails.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/config/application.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/Rakefile:20:in `require'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/Rakefile:20:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:94:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/config/application.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/Rakefile:20:in `require'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/Rakefile:20:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
NameError: uninitialized constant Pry::Prompt
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pry-rails-0.3.5/lib/pry-rails/prompt.rb:36:in `<module:PryRails>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pry-rails-0.3.5/lib/pry-rails/prompt.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/pry-rails-0.3.5/lib/pry-rails.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/config/application.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/Rakefile:20:in `require'
/home/nicola/iqvoc_2/Rakefile:20:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:96:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in `load_rakefile'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:79:in `block in run'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/nicola/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I am using ubuntu 14.0.6 and ruby 2.4

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` already? It seems to have trouble finding the namespace for pry

Comment: yes :\ and everything else is working pretty nicely too

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar error with a Rails 3 project using jazz_hands. This is just a shot in the dark, but try this:

```
bundle update pry-rails pry-remote pry-byebug
```

And then see if the error is fixed.